# How to add contributors (collaborators) to a npm package?

Tags: npm, code-collaborator

I created a `npm` package few months ago, and a friend was nice enough to help me make the original project into a package and upload it to `npm`.
Now I'm an owner of the package but only he is shown under collaborators. As it is my package and I did most of the work I would love to be mentioned as a collaborator.

We tried `npm owner add` but it didn't help.

Here is the package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-singular-component

BTW: I am an owner.

Comment: I see you are now both listed as collaborators. Did you work out what to change?

Comment: I spoke with npm support there's seems to be a defective cache

Answer (score 6):

The npm `collaborators` (in the website) is the `owner` (in the command line).

> Note: [owners are people with the ability to publish new versions of the package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-owner) so you may not want to add everyone as an owner for security reasons.

Please run the following command on your terminal:

`npm owner add <user> [<@scope>/]<pkg>`

Where the  parameter is the NPM username of the collaborator to include. It goes without saying: the collaborator must have an NPM account to be included.

See the [`npm owner` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-owner).

Answer (score -1):

To be more specific, I think you're looking for some sort of way to display all contributors in your package.
There's an `npm package` called [All-Contributors](https://allcontributors.org/docs/en/cli/installation) which you can use to generate a nice looking grid of contributors with their github profile photos.

You can install it by running:

```sh
yarn add -D all-contributors
```

Initialize your project with:

```sh
yarn all-contributors init
```

you can add a contributor by running

```sh
yarn all-contributor add <github-username> doc
```

Checkout the [docs](https://allcontributors.org/docs/en/overview) for more information on how to use the package.